# Simple rhythmbox plugins do not work - why?

Tags: 11.10, rhythmbox, plugins, gtk3

[Simple Rhythmbox plugins](http://sites.google.com/site/undo13/home/simple-rhythmbox-plugins) do not work in 11.10. Does anybody know why? I heard that ubuntuone plugin for Rhythmbox stopped working because some changes to Rhythmbox - might this be the same case?

More information: I followed [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/simple-rhythmbox-plugins-save-cover-in.html) guide, i.e. I copied the plugin to ~/.gnome2/rhythmbox/plugins, but they do not show up in Edit>plugins. I suspect it might be due to the plugins not being ported to GTK3?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Provided more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rhythmbox plugins are now located in the following directory

```
~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins
```

However even when you copy the Simple Rhythmbox Plugins to that directory such won't appear in the plugins view as such plugins are not compatbile with the rhythmbox version available for 11.10 and higher.

Such plugins need to be ported. See [Introduction to Rhythmbox plugins](http://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/WritingGuide) for details. Also take a look at [the plugins available](http://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/ThirdParty) for Rhytmbox. There might be a substitute suitable for you.